# Modeling sequence of events in Alloy

Tags: alloy

The following model represents a sequence of actions given a certain pre-defined order.

```
open util/ordering[Time]

abstract sig Action {pre: set Action}

one sig A, B, C, D extends Action {}

fact{
    pre = A -> B + D -> B + D -> C
}

sig Time { queue: Action -> lone State}

abstract sig State {}
one sig Acted, Ok, Nok extends State{}

pred Queue [t, t': Time] {
   some a: Action-(t.queue).State |
       a.pre in (t.queue).Ok + (t.queue).Nok and t'.queue=t.queue+(a->Acted)
}

pred Reply [t, t': Time] {
   some a: (t.queue).Acted | 
          some s: State-Acted | t'.queue=t.queue++(a->s)
}

fact {
  no first.queue 
  last.queue=Action->Ok or last.queue = Action -> Nok
  all t:Time-last | Queue[t,t.next] or Reply[t,t.next]
}


run {last.queue=Action->Ok and some t:Time-last | t.queue = Action->Nok} for 9
```

With the run I would like to have a sequence where the last queueing action goes OK but some action failed before. However I don't get any instance. 
Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Regards, Andre.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that once an action has, at a given time, a state which is `Nok` then it can't be changed back to another state in a future time(as suggested by the two quantifier in the `Queue` and `Reply` predicates).

The analyzer thus can't find an instance where in the final Time, all the actions are in an `Ok` state and where at a given time an action is in a `Nok` State. (This is what you request in your run command)

Hope it helps